# What do I need to use for Game Development in C#?

Tags: c#, game-engine

I have read a lot about the XNA framework going away and Microsoft not openly supporting it any more. I would like to know if there are any similar technologies available keeping in mind that I do not want to pay a lot of $$ for creating a cross platform indie game.. I know that XNA only support Microsoft devices and that there are already a lot of open source game engines available such as [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/), [NeoAxis](http://www.neoaxis.com/) and so on. I am mainly looking for a simplified game engine where I can code in c#. I do not require the Complex 3D rendering component or worry to much about memory management. Just want to get a simplified tool set as a beginner. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unity3D is the answer to your problem. Although 3D is in the name, you can do just about any type of a game in Unity. It also supports game scripting in other languages like JS. There are plenty of examples, great support, and growing popularity. I believe they also have a free version of their engine. [www.unity3d.com](http://www.unity3d.com)

Answer (score 3):

If you want something similar to Microsoft's XNA you can always try [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which is an open-source implementation of XNA 4 and includes support for Windows, Windows Metro, Mac OSX, Linux, Android (with MonoDroid) and iOS (with Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch)